# Solving for an indicated variable where all the variables are under 1 in a fraction

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Solving a literal equation containing fractions.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184709/solving-a-literal-equation-containing-fractions)

1/R=(1/R1)+(1/R2) solve for R1. I can't figure out what to do, I always end up where I have to either get rid of R1 or an answer that doesn't work when plugging it back in.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

1) isolate 1/R1

2) simplify both sides of that isolation

3) figure out the two conditions for this to work

If this is not clear, ask again.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \frac{1}{R}= \frac{1}{R_1}  +\frac{1}{R_2}  $$

$$  \frac{1}{R_1}=\frac{1}{R}-\frac{1}{R_2}    $$

$$  R_1=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{R}-\frac{1}{R_2}} =  \frac{1}{\frac{R_2-R}{R\, R_2}}=  \frac{R\, R_2}{R_2-R}  . $$

Comment: Thank you for showing me how to get to the answer because the book I'm using did not give me the answer to the question so I was not sure if any of the answers I got were right.